# Multiple linear regression problem

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, matrix

[image: Past question paper problem.[1]]

I am stuck at this question. For example I have B=(X'X)^-1X'Y but I cannot go further and make He a part of the model. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Note that $H\epsilon$ is not a part of the model in the sense that you imply. You are trying to decompose the structure of $\hat{\mathbf{Y}}$, which is not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have
$$
\hat{\mathbf{Y}}=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{Y}
$$
Now you can replace $\mathbf{Y}$ in the equation above with $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}\beta + \epsilon$. Then you get
$$
\hat{\mathbf{Y}}=\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{X}\beta + \epsilon)
= \mathbf{H}\mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{H}\epsilon
$$
Now you need to find the expression for $\mathbf{H}$, (i.e. the *hat matrix*) plug it in the first term and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way. You have just to do some multiplications. Please check over here.
[image]